# Customizing ASP.NET Membership Tables

Tags: asp.net-membership

Can I adjust the ASP.NET Membership Tables to add some columns of my own? For example, I'd like to extend the Roles table by adding RoleCode containing the abbreviated name for the user role. It's just an example but is it possible? I know I'd have to adjust a few SPs and a bit of code in the app itself, but again, is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could, but why not just store the fields you want to add in the Profile Provider?  It's much easier and achieves the same thing without having to modify a thing in the sprocs or DB.  In addition, you also get strongly typed properties on the profile itself for coding against.

http://odetocode.com/Articles/440.aspx

Comment: Interesting, I honestly haven't looked into that yet.  I wonder, I'm planning to make a user privileges table (linked to a modules table and hopefully, the roles table, along with what CRUD the user can do).  Can profiles handle this as well?

Comment: unless there is a very compelling reason/need to customize the schema, which also implies custom provider implementations, using profile is the way to go 90% of the time.